# UHD 630 and 18.04 LTS

Tags: hardware

Hello does the Intel i3 8100 (UHD 630) work with the supported kernel in 18.04 LTS out of the box? I tried searching around and could't find this question. I plan on using full 1080p monitor not 4K

Comment: If you have the machine, download Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, write to thumb-drive & try it for yourself.  You don't need to install to 'try ubuntu'  (an option on the install media).

Comment: I dont have the PC yet and it'll be a custom build, that's the thing. Fresh boot